# Query to find duplicate data in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am new to SQL and have been unable to find any articles to explain the way I need to filter my data in order to pull duplicate tickets, from within a ticketing system. I need to check if a store submits multiple tickets in the same category on the same date. Below is a sample of what I'm working with. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
USE [HelpDesk]
declare 
@date1 date = '5-1-2017',
@date2 date = '6-2-2017' 

SELECT  [SectionName]
,[CategoryName]
,[RequesterName]
,[IssueDate]
,[StatusId]
FROM [HelpDesk].[dbo].[uvTESTMasterQueryIssues]
WHERE [IssueDate] > @date1 AND [IssueDate] < @date2;
```

[Data and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HnfT.jpg)

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are not the same. Please remove the RDBMS you are not using.

Comment: Add a `Group By` and `Having Count(1) > 1` to your `Select` statement

Comment: Add som sample data

Comment: Depending on the datatype for `IssueDate`, if it's `DateTime`, you will need to `Cast as Date` to get same dates.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get a chance to run or try it out but it should be something like this in SQL Server:

```
-- Number of occurrences of Duplicate records
SELECT [SectionName]
    ,[CategoryName]
    ,[RequesterName]
    ,[IssueDate]
    ,[StatusId]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [NUMBER OF OCCURENCES]
FROM [dbo].[uvTESTMasterQueryIssues]
WHERE [IssueDate] > @date1
    AND [IssueDate] < @date2
GROUP BY [SectionName]
    ,[CategoryName]
    ,[RequesterName]
    ,[IssueDate]
    ,[StatusId]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY [SectionName]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple query, you can use Group by and having to achieve what you want.

Please refer: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

create table #temp
(

```
IssueID int,
SectionName varchar(50),
CategoryName varchar(50),
RequesterName varchar(50),
IssueDate date
```

)
insert into #temp values(123,'Maintenance','Other Alarms','Store 0009550','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(124,'Maintenance','Other Alarms','Store 0003561','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(125,'Maintenance','Other Alarms','Store 0009550','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(126,'Maintenance','Other Alarms','Store 0003561','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(127,'Maintenance','Target Move','Store 0003561','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(128,'Maintenance','Other Alarms','Store 0007426','2017-05-17')
insert into #temp values(129,'Maintenance','Target Move','Store 0007750','2017-05-17')

select * from #temp

declare @date1 date = '5-1-2017'
declare @date2 date = '6-2-2017'

;with cts as (
select 
 [CategoryName]
,[IssueDate],RequesterName
FROM #temp
WHERE [IssueDate] between @date1 and @date2
Group by CategoryName, [IssueDate],RequesterName having count(*)>1
)

select t.* from #temp t inner join cts ON t.CategoryName=cts.CategoryName and t.IssueDate=cts.IssueDate and t.RequesterName=cts.RequesterName order by t.RequesterName,t.IssueID

drop table #temp

Comment: I know  you're not up to 50 yet to comment, but this is a comment, not an answer. Post a valid answer of code. Take their code and make it work for the desired result. You'll get more points doing that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicate records using group by, Like if you want to find duplicate record based on Category and requesterName then execute below query will give you result :

```
SELECT  [CategoryName]
,[RequesterName]
,Count(*)
FROM [HelpDesk].[dbo].[uvTESTMasterQueryIssues]
WHERE [IssueDate] > @date1 AND [IssueDate] < @date2
GROUP BY
    RequesterName, CategoryName
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Your group by needs to contain all columns that are not being aggregated.

Comment: But by this way you can find the duplicate records, remove the other columns not needed. Am I missing anything please let me know so that I can understand better

Comment: Did you run this code? This will give an error. That's all I'm saying. If you suggest an answer, please make sure it runs without errors.

Comment: Let me give a try and will update you ...Give me some time. Please share your create table query(your DML) so that I can test better. As I was not having the correct schema of table that's why didn't executed that ..Just give the rough Idea used in past.

Comment: This will not give what OP wants. They want to know if an issue was submitted more than once on same date. If you remove the date, then you are most likely to get duplicates, but could be for different dates.